# sending email every 5 minutes in net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

How to create a scheduler executing a task every 5 minutes in net core 2.0? It should work like cron in linux or unix environment. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: show us what you have done by your own

Comment: I have added an item to crontab but it looks not professional configuration. Could it be done by application itself?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Quartz.NET` or `Hanfire`.

Quartz.NET:https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet

Hanfire:https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire

And you can use `mailkit` to send email.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit